# Event on back elements doesn't trigger in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Alright, I have a chess board with all the spots and pieces. It's generated `onload` with two four cycles from a 2D array. The idea is, that you should be able to drag a chess piece (something I've already implemented correctly), and let it go in a valid position. The letting go part should trigger an event in the actual board spots. So each of the 64 spots have an even listener that looks like this.

```
element.on("mouseup",function(e){
                if(Game.current==undefined||!$(this).hasClass("valid")){return;}
                var col,row;
                col = $(this).attr("column");
                row = $(this).attr("row");
                Game.current.attr({
                    "column":col,
                    "row":row
                });
                Game.move(Game.current);
                Game.changeTurn();
                Game.current = undefined;

            });
```

The function triggers normally when I click on a square in the board, however when I drag and drop a chess piece there, it doesn't register that the mouse is up. It let's go of the piece, however since the cursor is directly over the chess piece and said piece "blocks" the cursor from being directly above the spot. It is also worth noting that my HTML structure is like this.

```
<board>
    <spot></spot>
    <piece></piece>
</board>
```

By which I mean, that the pawns, bishop etc. aren't inside the spots, so the event doesn't have anything to "bubble" through.

Comment: Define a global var to check if the mouse is up or down.

Comment: Instead of custom wiring it, you should perhaps consider using jqueryui's draggable and droppable. In addition to the above case getting automatically handled for you, it'll also let you concentrate on game logic instead of mouse event technicalities.

Comment: That was my original plan, but jQuery is the only library I'm allowed to use. In fact I have to use jQuery.

Comment: Oh. Ok. In that case, bind the mouseup to the board instead of to the spots. This way mouseup on the pieces can bubble up to the board. Once captured, determine the spot from the event coordinates inside the board. Kind of like what Stafno says below, but you don't need to let it bubble till the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be attach the listener of mouseup to the window object doing something like this

```
$(window).on('mouseup', on_mouse_up );
```

and then, from the mouse position calculating the right spot.

```
function on_mouse_up( e ) {
    // Get the mouse position
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;

    // Calculate the spot from the mouse position

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I feared I would have to use math.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    //console.log($);
    $('document').ready(function () {
        var target;
        $('#wrapper').mousedown(function (e) {
            var el = $(e.target);
            if (el.hasClass('elem')) {
                target = el;
            }
        });
        $('#wrapper').mouseup(function (e) {
            var el = $(e.target);
            //console.log(e);
            if (target) {
                if (el.hasClass('kletca')) {
                    el.append(target);
                }
            }
            target = undefined;
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32DTv/ a simple example